# Unable to open another excel file (when one Excel is opened by .net)

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, garbage-collection

I have designed a .net application which will open an Excel file at the time of login and use it to print a report. It will be closed while logging out the user. I set visible to false for Excel file, so that user doesn't know about the background process.

But if anybody opens any other Excel file during this time, my report Excel file becomes visible and the Excel object is collapsed. I have to go to task manager and kill the all open Excel instances to fix this.

**Code:**

```
 Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
            ConnectMe()
            Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand("uspLogin", Con)
            SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLoginName", UsernameTextBox.Text.Trim())
            SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", PasswordTextBox.Text.Trim())
            Adapter.SelectCommand = SQLCmd
            Adapter.Fill(dt)
            SQLCmd.Dispose()
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                Loading.Show()
                OpenAllTempaltes()            
                Me.Hide()                
                Con.Close()
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            Else
                MsgBox("Your Credential is Wrong !!!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login")
                UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
                PasswordTextBox.Text = ""              
                UsernameTextBox.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception         
            Application.Exit()
        End Try
    End Sub

 Public Sub OpenAllTempaltes()
        Try                                   
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Templates", "Excel_Templates_GST.xlsm"), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, True)                
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseAllTempaltes()
        Try
            CleanUp(xlApp, xlWorkBook, xlWorkSheet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionLog("PrintPage", "CloseAllTempaltes", ex.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm not sure the garbage collection tag applies in this case since it seems to be an issue between excel in the background as managed by your code, and when the user runs it manually. Can you post some of the code that you suspect might be causing it. And by collapsed, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Sure. Ill pot it.. @Fabulous

Comment: I also want to know the solution to this one. I also happened to encounter the same issue that while I'm reading and writing to an Excel file(A) (a long process btw, takes 5 to 10mins.) and another Excel file(B) has been opened, it shows (A), making my program to throw an error because an Excel file cannot be modified while being open. I suspect that it is because of the resources hogging (just a wild guess).

Comment: This might be useful: [Issue when 2 Excel apps running simultaneously. VB.NET](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/889aae38-fcb8-4e1c-a609-0bdf9c51ca13/issue-when-2-excel-apps-running-simultaneously-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `IgnoreRemoteRequests` property of the Excel application object:

`xlApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = True`

This is the equivalent of checking the Excel UI option at
File | Options | Advanced | General | Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE).
(See this [related answer](https://superuser.com/a/21604/356636) on SuperUser.)

I couldn't conveniently reproduce your scenario with a .NET application, but ran some tests by late binding an Excel.Application object from Word VBA and it worked as intended.  I created a hidden Excel application, and was able to perform actions on it before and after opening files by double-clicking in File Explorer.

In my tests, the setting was not still toggled on the next time I opened Excel normally, but you might want to capture its value and restore it before quitting your application object, in case that behavior isn't universal.

Edit: This behavior has been around since at least Excel 2003, and I verified using Excel 2016 (32-bit).

In Excel 2013 or later, Excel switched to a single document interface: each workbook opens in its own window.

At least through 2016, the Visual Basic Editor has remained a multiple document interface, and you can easily see which files are open in an application session by looking at the Project Explorer pane in the VBE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @VigneshKumar, please let me know if you need anything else to consider this answer complete/acceptable, and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: Could you indicate your Excel version for which this worked?  Excel 2013 was designed to combine instances (see: [Opening workbooks by running separate instances of Excel](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/)).  Unfortunately, my version is old so I can not verify this technique works on newer versions.

Comment: @TnTinMn Also, near the end of the article you linked it says "All existing application-level window methods, events, and properties are unaffected by this change." So they *promise* this still works.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem is caused by the same instance of xlApp.
What I would do is simple: I would initialize new instance of xlApp and then quite that instance of the application. This way it won't interfere with any other open instance of Excel. Here is how I use it in C#:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();  // by default this is invisible
```

do whatever you have to do with the new instance of xlApp and then quite the application. Once you quite the application it won't be in your task manager.

```
xlApp.Application.Quit();
```

I have designed several applications where I had to process the same Excel files that most likely would've been open by those same users. This approach (opening new instance of excel in invisible mode and then quitting the application) never caused any problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

If one excel file is open, and if you are editing a cell, you can't open a second Excel file until you stop editing that cell. You can hit "ESC" in your open document and that will get you out of editing the first file and should allow the second to open. I see that there are other solutions (I hope they worked) but I am guessing this may be the issue.